# How to compute complex SQL queries on react to backend and get the results

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have a react application that connects to a postgreSQL database through django rest framework. Currently, I am able to display serialized data from the backend to the frontend. The postgreSQL data I am generating is generated externally hence I am not handling any CRUD operations in django ORM. Just displaying the data.

I want to try something new. My idea is this :

1. Build an interface on react where I would type complex SQL queries to execute.
2. The SQL queries from the frontend need to be posted to the related django viewset for execution and generate the needed serialized data.
3. The data needs to be displayed back to the react frontend.

I would like to know if it is possible to execute this. And if it is, what would be the best way to execute?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it certainly is. This is how most web apps work these days.

1. Send the SQL queries as a string to the backend
2. The backend executes the queries on the database.
3. The backend returns the results to react.js. You can add a snapshot listener so that as soon as the results are ready, they are going to be delivered to the front end